# friendly_id_slugs Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

Working on another deployment & found that `rails generate friendly_id` (as recommended by the [Friendly_Id Documentation](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#rails-quickstart) creates a new table called `friendly_id_slugs` - is this right or legacy?

Comment: looks right as per the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html):

> FriendlyId's History module adds the ability to store a log of a
>   model's slugs, so that when its friendly id changes, it's still
>   possible to perform finds by the old id.
>
> The primary use case for this is avoiding broken URLs.
>
> ---
>
> **Setup**
>
> In order to use this module, you must add a table to your database
>   schema to store the slug records. FriendlyId provides a generator for
>   this purpose:
>
> rails generate friendly_id rake db:migrate This will add a table named
>   friendly_id_slugs, used by the FriendlyId::Slug model.